# How do I get certain values inside of an Array?

Tags: c++, arrays

I am doing a program which will calculate some stuff, for example I need to know how many employees are Female, It is on a file which I read and saved it on an Array of string. The data saved on the Array are F of Female, and M of male. How do I count how many F(Female) there are inside the Array? I already have everything set all I need to know is how to count the values inside an array, specific values inside it(Just the F) and not all values.

This is the code that reads the Gender(Used in the example):

```
File.open("Gender.txt");
    for(int i=0; i<100; i++){
        File >> gender[i];
    }
```

And this is the variable used to store them:

`string gender[100];`

Gender .txt File is like this:

```
F
F
M
F
M
M
F
F
F
F
M
M
F
M
F
F
M
F
F
M
F
```

Comment: What is the question you're asking? How to count specific elements of an array? Then just loop over the array, possibly while also reading into it, and check if e.g. `gender[i] == "F"` or `gender[i] == "M"`, increasing a `female_counter` or `male_counter` respectively.

Comment: *"how to count the values inside an array"*, [`std::count`/`std::count_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count)

Comment: Or perhaps use [`std::count_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count) if you want to count later.

Comment: Are you trying to reading a char into a variable of type int?

Comment: @TedLyngmo I determine if it's Female or Male because the file only contains M(Male) And F(Female) so all I need to do is count the F and the M to get how many Females or Males there are, but I don't know how to count that.

Comment: @KennyOstrom Oh that's not the right variable, let me edit it.

Comment: I see... it was an error in the question. How are F and M stored? One per line or is it just `MMFMFMFMMMFFFMFMMFMFMMFFMFMF` mixed? Please show a snippet of the data file too.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yes, because for the program I need to count how many are Female, how many are under 20 years old and stuff like that. All I needed is to know how to count specific values inside an Array so I can count all the other stuff I need.

Comment: How do you now if they are under 20? Show the data file please

Comment: @TedLyngmo The txt file I'm using for Female(M) and Male(M) it's like this:
F
F
M
F
M
M
F
F
F
F
M
M
F
M
F
F
M
F
F
M
F
M
F
F
F

Comment: @SaryxEze Please edit the question and put it in the question instead of here in the comments.

Comment: @TedLyngmo And this is the txt file for the age:
36.36
47.02
54.15
39.67
40.31
34.86
22.14
59.12
58.18
29.73
42.5
22.21
45.45
21.1
59.47
50.97
47.23
24.66
58.08
49.85
22.64
23.77
44.72
37.27

Comment: Again, put all the relevant information in the question.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Alright, Sorry I'm new here.

Comment: @SaryxEze Is it your teacher's idea to have the gender and age in different files? Are you free to change that?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yeah it was his idea, and we need to do it like that. There's a separate file for everything.

Comment: Are there any restrictions on what you can and can not use in the C++ language or in C++'s standard library?

Comment: @TedLyngmo No, there are no restrictions on what to use.

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to use a `std::vector<char>` to store `F`, `M` or what else that will be in the file. A `vector` can grow dynamically so you just have to read from the file and `push_back()` into the `vector`. When the file has been completely read, The `size()` member function will tell you how many entries you read from the file.

- Add `#include <vector>` to get access to `std::vector`
- Declare `std::vector<char> gender;` in `main` to keep the result.
- Declare a counter for `female` and `male`, initialize to zero.
- Open the file.
- Loop:

  ```
  char gen;
  while(File >> gen) {
      gender.push_back(gen);
      // if gen is an F, increase `female`
      // else if gen is an M, increase `male`
  }
  ```
- When the whole file is read, you can print the stats:

  ```
  std::cout << "Female: " << female << '\n'
            << "Male: " << male << '\n'
            << "Other: " << (gender.size() - female - male) << '\n';
  ```

Comment: Wow, that's good and simple to understand, Thanks a lot for your time and your patience

Comment: I just made it in the program and the counter works well! Now all I needs to do is repeat the same for the other stuff. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Use [`std::count_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count) of the algorithm header.

```
count_if( InputIt first, InputIt last, UnaryPredicate p );
```